# Error en ASP.NET consulta SQL: Must declare scalar variabe

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, webforms

```
protected void txtBusqueda_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CONEXION_BBDD"].ConnectionString))
        {
            sqlConn.Open();
            string consulta = " SELECT Ejercicio from Ejercicios WHERE Ejercicio like '%'+@eje+'%' ";
            
            try
            {
                
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(consulta, sqlConn))
                {

                    string eje = txtBusqueda.Text.ToString();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eje", eje);
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(consulta, sqlConn);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    da.Fill(dt);//error: Error SQL. Must declare the scalar variable @eje

                    GridView.DataSource = dt;
                    GridView.DataBind();
                }
                    
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

        }

    }
```

Tengo un cuadro de texto de búsqueda que cuando el texto cambia se llama a este evento.
Este evento hace una consulta y actualiza el gridview.

Pero me aparece una excepción SQL sobre declarar una variable "@eje":

**Must declare the scalar variable @eje**

No veo donde está el problema, ya que añado esa variable como parámetro antes de ejecutar la query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que tienes algún punto a cambiar.

```
string consulta = " SELECT Ejercicio from Ejercicios WHERE Ejercicio like @eje ";

            try
            {

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(consulta, sqlConn))
                {
                    string eje = "%"+txtBusqueda.Text.ToString()+"%";
                    cmd.Connection.Open();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eje", eje);
                    
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    da.Fill(dt);//error: Error SQL. Must declare the scalar variable @eje

                    GridView.DataSource = dt;
                    GridView.DataBind();
                }
```

Esto debería de funcionarte. Se puede hacer de otras maneras, pero puedes concatenar el % % a lo que te viene de la caja de texto, y así la query no lleva nada. Directamente el parámetro.
El dataAdapter lo abres sobre el comando. Y la conexión la abre el comando.